# Fingerprint support in Lenovo T530

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T530 running Ubuntu 20.04. Like most thinkpads, it comes with a fingerprint reader. Without installing anything, ubuntu doesn't detect my reader. I proceded to install `fprint` and `libfprint`, but they both return `Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available`  which from what I understand, means it doesn't detect the reader. Are there any drivers that let me add support?

Results of `lsusb`:

```
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f2:b2ea Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera [ThinkPad]
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 012: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd USB Optical Mouse
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the Terminal output of `lsusb`. With this information, it will be possible to let you know whether the fingerprint reader has device drivers for Linux or not 

Comment: I added them, what now @matigo?

Comment: Based on the output of `lsusb`, it looks like the Linux kernel cannot even detect the fingerprint reader. Unfortunately, this means you'll have to wait until someone can reverse engineer the reader and add it to the kernel. Given how most fingerprint sensor manufacturers refuse to make their hardware documentation available to driver writers, you could be waiting a very, very long time ...

Comment: One more thing @matigo , the BIOS doesn't detect the reader either, does that mean it's broken hardware wise?

Comment: Most likely, yes. If the device firmware cannot initialize it, then it’s highly unlikely that any OS will make it work. There’s a lot more hardware *not* in your computer than there is inside the case. If an OS could initialize hardware not seen by a BIOS, it would need to spend a remarkable amount of time looking for devices that likely do not exist … 

Comment: I am on a laptop, and the fingerprint reader is built in, so I'm pretty sure its just broken hardware-wise.